# How to stop sending email for : DNS Server Timeout Error Number: 1460?

Tags: stoperror, email

I got this error code in bounce email. How do I stop sending the email to that particular user? Because I know the user's email address is not valid, his email is like:

jshddsj@jhbbsdkjcsdbdsc.com

My mail server is: MailEnable

I am using php, using imap to read the emails..

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the article in the MailEnable KB about DNS settings?

http://www.mailenable.com/kb/Content/Article.asp?ID=me020043

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if correct DNS IP is mentioned 
   mailenable > connector > smtp > dns ip
2. Run these test to check if your DNS is working properly or not
   http://www.mailenable.com/kb/content/article.asp?ID=ME020292

Comment: Please post the key points from the linked page into your answer in case the link ever dies.